# Python Bokeh possible bug, only last figure is shown

Tags: python, bokeh

Python 3.7.4, Windows 10, Bokeh 1.3.4.

Steps to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh import plotting as plt

y = np.asarray([4, 5, 6])
z = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
x = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
y_figure = plt.figure()
y_figure.line(x, y)
z_figure = plt.figure()
z_figure.line(x, z)
plt.show(y_figure)
plt.show(z_figure)
```

Run the above as a script, not a Jupyter Notebook. Two webpages will appear, as expected, but both are showing the last figure (`z_figure`). You can verify that by inspecting the vertical axis.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a bug. If you don't specify an output filename explicity, Bokeh `show` uses the name of the currently running script. So by not providing a name, and executing `show` twice, you are overwriting the output from the first with the second. The solution is to be explicit:

```
output_file("y.html")
plt.show(y_figure)

output_file("z.html")
plt.show(z_figure)
```

Comment: what if i don't want to save the file?

Comment: Unless you are asking about embedding in another web page, e.g. in a Flask or Django app, or displaying inline in a Jupyter notebook, then there *must* be a file saved, because the browser needs a file to load. All the various ways to embed Bokeh content are in the docs: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html